# Delete and Insert simultaneously on a oracle table

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table X and table Y .
There is a java subscriber that inserts data continously on X .
On X we have a insert trigger that , dumps data into Y on each insert.
I want to delete the processed records from Y , while simultaneous inserts are happening on Y.
Will the delete on Y encounter a lock

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't. Unless otherwise specified in your DML, locks occur on a row level. See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021531/5537052).